# how to solve "ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 16, 16, 3), found shape=(16, 16, 3)"?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to add tf.data pipeline to a regression task. The code starts with reading in the continues values using the csv file and inputting the images with cv2.imread. I split the data to train, test and validation using sklearn preprocessing.

```
print (trainY.shape,valY.shape,testY.shape,trainX.shape,valX.shape, testX.shape)
(159, 1) (69, 1) (58, 1) (159, 16, 16, 3) (69, 16, 16, 3) (58, 16, 16, 3)
```

In the text step, I define the tf datasets for train, test and validation.

```
tr_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY))
vl_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valX, valY))
te_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testX, testY))
```

here is a part of the model:

```
inputShape = (16, 16, 3)
chanDim = -1
inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding="same")(inputs)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
..
..
..
x = Dense(4)(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Dense(1, activation="linear")(x)

model = Model(inputs, x)

SGD = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05, momentum=0.2, decay=0.0, nesterov=False)
model.compile(optimizer=SGD, loss='mean_squared_error')

history=model.fit(tr_ds,
                  validation_data=vl_ds,
                  epochs=100,
                  batch_size=2,
                  verbose=2)
```

Fitting the model returns error about shape issue of model and input data. Can anyone help me to solve that?

Error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model: expected shape=(None, 16, 16, 3), found shape=(16, 16, 3)
```

Prediction and plotting:

```
preds = model.predict(testX)

plt.plot  ( testY ,label="Actual temp")
plt.plot  ( preds, label="Predicted temp" )
plt.title ('temp estimation')
plt.xlabel("Point #")
plt.ylabel("temp")
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.savefig("temp_estimation.png")
plt.show()
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: add this parameter in the Model constructor

Comment: input_shape = (16, 16, 3)

Comment: @ Cristofor  Thanks for the reply. This is already in the first line of the model. What do you mean by Model constructor?

Comment: model = Model(inputs, x, input_shape = (16, 16, 3))

Comment: @ Cristofor I added this argument, but this returns "TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input_shape')"

Comment: @Cristofor Model object has no argument name ``input_shape``

Comment: @rayan It is because model expects a batch dimension also. The first dimension is batch. How did you define ``tr_ds`` variable?

Comment: @ Kaveh thanks for your comment. I added the beginning of my code to the question. please have a look.

Comment: Would  you please batch you data once you define? for example : ``tr_ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY)).batch(2)``  for train and val dataset. and then remove ``batch_size`` argument from ``model.fit``.Test it. I think it will resolve your problem.

Comment: @ Kaveh Thanks for your solution. It was successful. sorry for extra question. Would you please see the last part of the question. I am not sure how I should related te_ds with preds and what should be there instead of testY and preds for creating the plot.

Comment: @rayan Just batch ``te_ds`` and pass it to your model to get predictions. The rest of code (testY and preds) is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that the expected dimension has not been passed to the model. The first dimension model expects is the batch. So, batch your data before pass it to the `model.fit()` like this:

```
tr_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY)).batch(2)
vl_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valX, valY)).batch(2)
te_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testX, testY)).batch(2)
```

And if you pass a dataset object to `model.fit()` you have not to specify `batch_size`. So you can remove this argument.

Comment: Please see the plot at the end of question.  it shows the true length for the predictions, but for the actual data this is close to all data which is around 286. do you know how can I correct the plot?

Comment: @rayan: Seems that both of ``testY`` and ``preds`` are in right shape (58,1). But because the plot ``testY`` is in a continuous line and the data is not sorted, the plot may confuse you. Plot in scatter for a better intuition. For example ``plt.plot(testY, 'ro')`` and
``plt.plot(preds, 'go')``.